# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.598.248'

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

[image]

how do i convert a number dataframe column in millions to double or float

```
0   1.598.248
1   1.323.373
2   1.628.781
3   1.551.707
4   1.790.930
5   1.877.985
6   1.484.103

0   15982480.0
1   13233730.0
2   16287810.0
3   15517070.0
4   17909300.0
5   18779850.0
6   14841030.0
```

Comment: Would be nice to know how you arrived at that point. It might be better to deal with separators when importing your data. For example, if you have imported the data using read_csv function that there is a `sep` argument that deals with that.

Comment: @ardms. Good point!

Answer (score 1):

```
  my_col_name
0   1.598.248
1   1.323.373
2   1.628.781
3   1.551.707
4   1.790.930
5   1.877.985
6   1.484.103
```

With the `df` above, you can try below code, with 3 steps: (1) change column type to string, (2) do string replace character, (3) change column type to float

```
col = 'my_col_name'
df[col] = df[col].astype('str')
df[col] = df[col].str.replace('.','')
df[col] = df[col].astype('float')
print(df)
```

Please note the above will result in a warning: `FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.`

So you could use below code with `regex=True`, also, I've combined in 1 line:

```
df[col] = df[col].astype('str').str.replace('.','', regex=True).astype('float')
print(df)
```

Output

```
   my_col_name
0   15982480.0
1   13233730.0
2   16287810.0
3   15517070.0
4   17909300.0
5   18779850.0
6   14841030.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the full stops. You can use pandas replace method then convert it into a float:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].replace('\.', '', regex=True).astype('float')
```

**Example**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.1.1', '2.1.2', '3.1.3', '4.1.4']})
>>> df

       A
0  1.1.1
1  2.1.2
2  3.1.3
3  4.1.4

>>> df['col'] = df['col'].replace('\.', '', regex=True).astype('float')
>>> df['A']

       A
0  111.0
1  212.0
2  313.0
3  414.0

>>> df['A'].dtype

float64
```

I'm assuming that because you have two full stops that the data is of type string. However, this should work even if you have some integers or floats in that column as well.